# Why do some parts of my object disappear when viewing the render viewport from certain angles?

Tags: rendering

So I dont know a whole lot about blender, just the basics. I am trying to build a 3d model of a room in my house. Following a tutorial online to make the wood look more photo realistic, I added a PBR shader to the object. The floor becomes all distorted when viewing it from certain angles. The guy that did the tutorial had his looking nice and I thought I followed it precisely, but I can't figure out why this is happening. See the screenshots for a better explanation.
[image]
[image]

Comment: i don't think it "disappears" as such, but starts reflecting the background world colour, like a mirror

Comment: it's a bit too glossy and probably not enough normal map effect, but we can't see what's happening within the node group, so maybe pack the images and share your file

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a Principled BSDF shader, but since you are following a tutorial, try increasing the roughness to see if that helps minimize how much of the environment is being reflected.